# Any way to determine the applied sequence of a matrix chain multiplication? (or simpler cases tetrahedron attachment, finite field, rotation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, finite-fields, computational-complexity

**General problem**
Given a starting matrix $S$ and an ending matrix $E$ and $m$ ($>1$) transforming square matrices $M_i$.
It is know that $E$ can be constructed out of $S$ by applying a sequence of matrix multiplications like:
$$E = ((SM_{i_1})M_{i_2})M_{i_3}... = S \prod_{j=1}^{N_M} M_{i_j}$$
$$i_j \in \{1,..,m\}$$

Given $E$, $S$ and all $M_i$ is there any (efficient) way to determine any sequence of matrix multiplications which is able to construct $E$ out of $S$?
($N_M$ is unknown. If there are multiple solutions just one is sufficient. In best case this with smallest $N_M'$)

---

**Example**
Let $m = 4$ and $E = SM_3M_2M_1M_4M_1M_4M_3M_2M_4$
Given $E,S,M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4$. I'm looking for a way to efficiently determine the sequence $[3,2,1,4,1,4,3,2,4]$ (or any other sequence with same result) without testing any possible multiplication.

---

**Possible simplification for tetrahedrons**
More specific I'm looking for a solution related to attached regular tetrahedrons (triangular pyramid)
Given a the vertices of regular tetrahedron $A,B,C,D$ an attached tetrahedron (attached to one side triangular face) can be constructed by reflection one vertex at the plane defined by the three other vertices. E.g. to construct A' out of A this would be:
$$A' = (B+C+D)\cdot \frac{2}{3}-A$$
The starting matrix $S$ would be defined as:
$$S = [A\text{ }B\text{ } C\text{ } D] = \begin{bmatrix}
A_x & B_x & C_x & D_x\\
A_y & B_y & C_y & D_x\\
A_Z & B_z & C_z & D_y\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$m=4$ transformation matrices $M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4$ would exist which are very similar to each other. E.g.
$$M_1 =M_A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{2}{3} & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{2}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

As those $M_i$ are similar to each other and much more limited than a random $M$ would this make finding a multiplication chain in between $S$ and $E$ easier?

---

**Simplification 2 or even harder in finite field?** 
Even more specific I'm looking for a solution applied to attached regular tetrahedrons in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_P$ with $P$ a prime.
Not much would change at the formula above. Just the the division need to be replaced by the inverse (for $M_i$ as well).
$$A' \equiv (B+C+D)\cdot 2 \cdot (3)^{-1}-A \mod P$$

Would this make finding a sequence for given $S$, $E$ easier or even harder?

---

**Simplification 3 rotation**
Instead of storing the tetrahedron position just storing the rotation would be enough for target application.
The tetrahedron center would be:
$$ T = (A+B+C+D)\cdot (4)^{-1} \mod P$$
And the starting rotation would be:
$$S = [A\text{ }B \text{ } C \text{ }D]-T \mod P $$
This would define the direction vector from center to each vertex.
($M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4$ need to be changed as well.)

Finding a sequence from $S$ to $E$ would reducing the problem to finding a tetrahedron with same rotation. (This won't be to be the same solution as for above including the position)

---

Or is this problem equivalent to another (better studied) problem?

Comment: I think that your issue is tantamount to find the shortest path in a graph (graph in the sense of "theory of graphs") from a vertex $V_1$ to a vertex $V_2$ (where the vertices are matrices).  Similar to the Cayley graph of a group, for example the Cayley graph of the group of transformations leaving invariant the tetrahedron. Once this graph is built, you can use it many times for different queries.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, I forgot to mention the target size of $P$ is some big number. Unless I understood it wrong this graph would include all possible tetrahedron. The number of possible tetrahedron grow very fast with $P$. For big $P$ there wouldn't be enough memory/time available. So I'm looking for a way without computing all solutions.

Comment: Maybe I haven't well understood your problem but thinking in terms of graphs is probably a good thing : In my proposal 1) Matrices are on vertices and also are "weighing" the edges (transformation matrices in this case). 2) You do not need to really build the graph ; it can be virtual...

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry, I dont know how this should work out. While searching the shortest path which direction should be considered as next step? If I go for breadth-first search there will be too many branches after a short time.

Comment: Have you heard about [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie ye, but this still need a definition for 'shortest'. If we just take the number of applied matrix multiplications this won't work out if many multiplication have been done. E.g. at a deep of 50 there are $4^{50} \approx 10^{30}$ nodes. No computer on earth can compute that many nodes.